# Why would I break the flags?

Tags: neptunia-v

When you learn about the Scout System the game teaches you about flags you can stand/break in the dungeons. I haven't noticed any real differences but I've always stood up the flags, because the tutorial hints that you get better bonuses (there was a + after the bonus  on the "with flag" image).

Should I always stand the flags up, or is there a reason to break them ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag (broken or fixed) changes the monster and items that appear when your scout informs you that the dungeon you sent them to has been changed. That is the actual bonus that the tutorial is talking about.

Flag fixed: Gathering spots will provide you with chip related items that can be used for modifying your CD accessory (or gathering quests), marked on the overworld as **Gather Shift +1**. It also turns the normal dangerous foe in that dungeon into the **Tough Foe**, who usually drops a Medal.

Flag broken: Gathering spots will provide you with monster related drop items that can be used for your item development (or gathering quests), marked on the overworld as **Gather Shift**. It also turns the normal dangerous foe in that dungeon into the **Risky Foe**, who usually drops an Idea Chip.

Remember: these changes only occur after your scout returns and tells you that either new items can be gathered from the dungeon, or that enemy positions have changed in the dungeon. Trusting has no downside, so always trust these (unless you are avoiding overriding an earlier report that you want from an earlier scout in the same dungeon).

Comment: Just to add a related note on this - in dungeons that have multiple maps, they will appear to have multiple flags but all flags are linked, so if you break it in one map, it'll be broken in all maps for that dungeon, and likewise for standing the flag.